# XLS конвертировать в CSV

Tags: php, xls

Подскажите кто знает способ открыть `XLS`-файл как массив или способ конвертации в `CSV`-файл с помощью `PHP`.

Ответ: PHPExcel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SimpleExcel](https://github.com/faisalman/simple-excel-php) вам в помощь.

Comment: Интересует именно XLS (старый формат), а не XLSX.

Comment: Тогда вот вам [PHPExcel][1] и [пример][2] его применения.

  [1]: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/
  [2]: http://www.binarytides.com/convert-excel-to-csv-in-php/